# A problem during real data analysis with purrr

Tags: r

I analyzed an real data set,

Data set: https://github.com/ThinkR-open/datasets/blob/master/README.md

```
tweets <-  readRDS("#RStudioConf.RDS")

rstudioconf <- as.list(NULL)

for (i in 1:nrow(tweets)) {
  rstudioconf[[i]] <- tweets[i,]
}
```

I want to answer question from data set: **how many tweets contain a link to a GitHub related URL?**

below is my code:

```
# Extract the "urls_url" elements, and flatten() the result
urls_clean <- map(rstudioconf, "urls_url") %>%
  flatten()

# Remove NA from list 
compact_urls <-  urls_clean %>%
  map(discard,is.na) %>% 
  compact()

# Create a mapper that detects the patten "github"
has_github <- as_mapper(~ str_detect(.x, "github"))

# Look for the "github" pattern, and sum the result
**map_lgl(compact_urls, has_github) %>% sum()
```

The *last line* of code

> map_lgl(compact_urls, has_github) %>% sum()

gives me an error:

> Error: Result 10 must be a single logical, not a logical vector of length 2

I am really confused, the code `map_lgl(compact_urls, has_github)` should give a logical vector with `TRUE` and `FALSE`, next this vector was piped into `sum()` and `TRUE` values were summed up and finally return a number. I never wonder it will give me an error. Could anyone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map_lgl` returns the error because some of the `list` elements have different `length`.  It is indicated in `?map`

> map_lgl(), map_int(), map_dbl() and map_chr() return an atomic vector of the indicated type (or die trying).

```
out <- map(compact_urls, has_github)
table(lengths(out))

#   1    2    3    6 
#1117   22    4    1
```

We can `unlist` the output from `map` and get the `sum`

```
sum(unlist(out))
```

---

It can be reproduced using a simple example

```
map_lgl(list(FALSE, TRUE), I) #each list element of length 1
#[1] FALSE  TRUE

map_lgl(list(FALSE, c(TRUE, TRUE)), I) # one element of length 2
```

> Error: Result 2 must be a single logical, not a vector of class `AsIs`
>   and of length 2

---

In case, if the objective is to return only a single TRUE/FALSE, then wrap the function with `any`

```
has_github <- as_mapper(~ any(str_detect(.x, "github")))
```

Now, try with `map_lgl`

```
map_lgl(compact_urls, has_github) %>% 
         sum()
#[1] 347
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. If I use `any`, then the result might be wrong in this data set because it is combine 2/3/6 logical results into 1, do you know what is logic for a single result for T,F,T,F,T,T? `&` or `|` ?  `unlist` returns perfect result.

Comment: @Steve  `any` is checking if there are any TRUE value in each `list` element after the `str_detect` `unlist` breaks the `list` structure and creates a single vector `list(c(1, 2), 3, 4) %>% unlist` will be of length 4 while the `list` was of length 3 and if you use `any` it would be length 3